# How do I enable "Factory Reset Protection" in Lollipop

Tags: factory-reset, 5.0-lollipop

I keep reading that Android 5.0 has "Factory Reset Protection", the so-called "Kill Switch" soon to be mandated in California, but that it's opt-in.  How do I opt in?  I've looked thru settings, including using the Settings search, but haven't found anything that sounds like this.  I'm on a Nexus 5.

Comment: I'm honestly a little skeptical that this feature even exists, either because it never did or it got cut before release. I have yet to find an official source that indicates that it does, just a lot of news/blog sites reporting it. It certainly is very widely reported to exist, though.

Comment: This might be 5.1 only, but it definitely exists.

Answer (score 1):

In speaking with Motorola Support through some reliable channels, here's what they said: "Since all comments regarding Factory Reset Kill is not approved yet by Motorola, we cannot give you the answer". In other words, it's not released, you won't find the option available yet and they can't tell you why. As of 1/20/2015.